# PineScript V5 Plot UDT array values

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to plot a line of series prices in TradingView using Pine Script v5. I am using User-Defined Type (UDT) for my FairValue, which contains the Date and its Price Value. My problem is I do not know how to plot FairValueArray.Value and only plot if the time is less than or equal to FairValue.Date. The code below was executed, but it only shows a single line with the last value from the array.

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fk9sg.png)

```
//@version=5
indicator("Fair Value Plot", "", true)

type FairValue
    int Date
    float Value

FairValueArray = array.new<FairValue>()

array.push(FairValueArray, FairValue.new(timestamp("20 Nov 2023 00:00 +0000"), 245))
array.push(FairValueArray, FairValue.new(timestamp("11 Dec 2023 00:00 +0000"), 260))
array.push(FairValueArray, FairValue.new(timestamp("20 Dec 2023 00:00 +0000"), 220))
array.push(FairValueArray, FairValue.new(timestamp("09 Jan 2024 00:00 +0000"), 211))

float Fairprice = 0

for FV in FairValueArray    
    label.new(FV.Date, FV.Value, str.tostring(FV.Value, format.mintick), xloc.bar_time, textcolor = color.white)
    startTimestamp = time
    endTimestamp = FV.Date
    // Check if the current bar is within the date range
    withinDateRange =  time >= startTimestamp and time <= endTimestamp  
    if withinDateRange     
        Fairprice := FV.Value
  
   
// Plot the price level if within the date range
plot(Fairprice)
```

I am expecting this kind of output:
[image: expected output]

I tried this, but it giving me error "Object has no field Value".

```
plot(FairValueArray.Value, color=color.blue, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pine script does not allow you to use plot inside for loop. If the list is not dynamic, you can use plot for each price. please check this thread
[How to pinescript plot values from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68569646/how-to-pinescript-plot-values-from-an-array)